# I am looking for one word to summarise a way of being

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes the following:

> *living congruently with the example one wants to set for others to
>   follow.*

Comment: Is there a word for not being a hypocrite?  For practicing what you preach?  Obviously, there are a lot of expressions for not doing so, but I can't think of any for doing so.  Maybe that's because it's generally expected.  We tend to call people out for not being true to what they expect from others but not for staying true.

Comment: Model citizen? Or just model.

Answer (score 3):

I think [*exemplar*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exemplar) is the most apropos example of a *shining example* of a *role model*.

> an ideal model

Answer (score 1):

*Authentic* would be a good word, in my opinion.

- Living an authentic life
- Living authentically
- Authentic living